# LSL but updating right bits with 1 rather than 0

Tags: assembly, arm64

I need an instruction similar to LSL but the bits on the right must be filled with 1 rather then 0.
Something like:

```
mov x0, 1
XXX x0, 3 -> here I should have 1111 in x0.
```

Comment: Not just shifting in copies of the sign bit, you mean unconditionally shifting in ones?  ARM/AArch64 doesn't have that built-in in hardware, but you could create a value that has the high `n` bits set and OR it with a shift result.  Is your shift count always immediate, or do you need to also support runtime-variable shift counts?

Comment: @PeterCordes I need something dynamic, I'll shift the bits according to a number on another register (like X1). This is the reason I cannot just create a value for that.

Comment: `(LONG_MIN>>(n-1)) | (x>>n)` should work, using arithmetic right shift.  Or maybe something like `-(1<<(64-n))`.  Whichever of those is cheaper to implement, including fixing any off-by-one errors I might have had, or handles corner cases like `n=0` correctly.

Comment: Oh, I was misreading this, I was thinking LSR shifting in ones at the *top* (like ASR does when the MSB was 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there isn't a single instruction that will do this. From your example, it's hard to say if you want something like the arithmetic right shift that will fill based on the least significant bit (either one or zero depending on the value of the LSb) or just an always fill with ones instead of zeroes. Either way, you can achieve similar result in 2/3 instructions:

```
MOV x0, #1

/* For the fill with LSb case */
RBIT x0, x0  /* reverse the bit order of the register */
ASR x0, x0, #3 /* use arithmetic right shift to do the shift, it will fill with the old LSb, now MSb */
RBIT x0, x0 /* fill bits back */ 

/* For the fill with 1s case */
MVN x0, x0 /* bitwise not the value of the register */
MVN x0, x0, LSL #3 /* shift the register value, filling with 0s, then invert the register again, restoring the original bits and flipping the filled 0s to 1s */

/* From the comments, it looks like OP wants the shift to come from another register and not a constant like in their post so the above needs an extra instruction */
MOV x1, #3 /* load the shift amount into a register */
MVN x0, x0
LSL x0, x0, x1 /* need a separate instruction to use a register instead of a constant as the shift amount */
MVN x0, x0
```

Comment: Note that AArch64 flexible second operand only works for constant shift counts.  For the OP's actual problem (in comments) of runtime-variable shift, you'll need a separate `lsl` instruction between `mvn`.  But nice idea, this is better for total instruction count (and equal or better for critical path latency) to my idea of constructing a value to ORR in.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, if you want to use a register as the shift instead of a constant, you'll need an extra instruction; but again, the example given does leave it a bit unclear what's needed; if the shift is known at assembly time, you can use my suggestion, if it's not known until runtime (ie, the shift is from memory/a register), you'll need that extra instruction.

Comment: Now I see that comment, yes, you need the extra instruction, I'll update the example to reflect that

Comment: Yeah, it's not a good question.  There's a big difference between a compile-time constant and a runtime variable in a register when you're programming in asm!